# not able to connect database in dotnetcore webapi(sqlserver)

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on .NETCore 2 Web API. I started working on the local database with the connection string as presented in the following snippet of code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

  services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors", builder =>
  {
    builder
      .AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader();
  }));

  services.AddMvc();

  var connection = @"Server=.;Database=ESociety;Trusted_Connection=True;";
  services.AddDbContext<ESocietyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
  services.AddScoped<IArtistRepository, ArtistRepository>();
}
```

It is working fine.

Then I changed to database connection string to point in smarterasp server. 
I am able to connect to the database in smarterasp server via SSMS.

But I am not able to connect through a Web API.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

  services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors", builder =>
  {
    builder
      .AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader();
  }));

  services.AddMvc();

  var connection = @"Server=sql6***.site4now.net;Database=[dbname];Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=[username];password=[password]";
  services.AddDbContext<ESocietyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
  services.AddScoped<IArtistRepository, ArtistRepository>();
}
```

Have I missed anything or is the connection string I created not correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this part from your connection string

```
Trusted_Connection=True
```

or it will try to connect to the database using your windows credentials.

So the working string should be

```
@"Server=sql6***.site4now.net;Database=[dbname];User Id=[username];password=[password]"
```

you can read about the differences here:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/